# why title_img is undefined ? and the other are working?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a upload btn named title_img and upload btn for multiple images.

why it shows the title_img as undefined ?

```
        <form method="post" class="add-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <section class="flex flex-row flex-wrap file-c">
            <section class="relative">
              <!--default html file upload button-->
              <input type="file" name="title_img" id="titel-img" />

            </section>

            <section class="relative">
              <!--default html file upload button-->
              <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="actual-btn" hidden/>

              <!--our custom file upload button-->
              <label for="actual-btn">Bilder Hochladen</label>
            </section>
          </section>
    
....
```

js

```
          const files = document.querySelector('#actual-btn').files;
          const form = new FormData();

          form.append('t_img', document.querySelector('#titel-img').files[0]);

          for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            form.append('files[]', file);
          }

          const res = await fetch('xxx.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: form
          });
          const data = await res.json();
...
```

php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/db.php';

  
        $path = '../img/cars/';

        $success = false;
        

        var_dump($_FILES['title_img']);
....
```

please nyone can help me
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: You are recreating the HTML form in JS, but you didn’t include `title_img` as far as I can tell.

Comment: "why it shows the title_img as undefined ?" - what does that mean? Is there any specific error message? Also, is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you append it to the FormData object as `t_img` not `title_img`